# fast-csv adds unwanted quotation mark to number

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv

I'm trying to write to csv with fast-csv in nodejs but somehow quotation marks appear in the csv which cause some problems.

> ```
>  await csv.write([
> ['Header1', 'Header2'], [firstnamestring, arrayofnumbers1], [secondnamestring, 
> arrayofnumbers2]
> ], {headers:true}).pipe('test.csv')
> ```

actual outcome:

```
Header1, Header2
Name, "1,2,2"  

Name, "3,3,4"
```

Desired outcome:

```
Header1, Header2
Name, 1,2,2
Name, 3,3,4
```

I logged the array of numbers right before and no quotation marks appear. I'm not sure where they come from.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome! You are trying to write invalid CSV. Since the CSV is comma-separated, values containing a comma should be escaped by embedding them in double quotes. Your desired outcome is actually invalid, because it has only 2 headers, followed by lines with 4 values each. I makes sense that fast-csv does't support this..

Comment: But looking at it (I don't know fast-csv actually), it seems you can just pass arrays of values of which the number is maybe not validated. If so, it may work if you flatten the array and instead of passing `["Name", [1,2,2]]`, you will pass `["Name", 1, 2, 2]` to fast-csv. to separate values. Instead of `[firstnamestring, arrayofnumbers1]`, you could do something like `arrayofnumbers1.unshift(firstnamestring)`, to have a flattened list of values with the first name at the front.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in a slightly different context: I was using`JSON.stringify(myArray)` as an element in the output CSV. `fast-csv` adds quotes for arrays with multiple elements as expected, but for empty arrays or arrays with only one element, it would not add quotes.

`@fast-csv/format` has the `quote` option for this purpose. Turning it to `false` removes the quotes from the output.

So I disabled the quotes and write them manually now. This is how to disable the quotes:

```
csv.format({
  headers: true,
  quote: false
});
```

Then I need to add the qoutes manually:

```
`"${JSON.stringify(myArray)}"`
```